# How can I justify the swap of the limit with the contour integral?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, derivatives

I want to show that if $f$ is analytic then $$f^{''}(w) = \frac{1}{\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-w)^3}\,dz.$$

Consider the following:

\begin{align}
f''(w)&=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f'(w+h)-f'(w)}{h}\\ \\
&=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2\pi i h} \left( \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-w-h)^2} dz-\oint_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-w)^2} \: dz \right) \\ \\
&=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{h} \left(\frac{1}{(z-w-h)^2} - \frac{1}{(z-w)^2}\right)  \: dz\\ \\
&=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{h} \left(\frac{1}{z-w-h} - \frac{1}{z-w}\right)\left(\frac{1}{z-w-h} + \frac{1}{z-w}\right)  \: dz\\ \\
&=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{h} \left(\frac{h}{(z-w-h)(z-w)}\right)\left(\frac{1}{z-w-h} + \frac{1}{z-w}\right) \:  dz\\ \\
&=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C f(z) \left(\frac{1}{(z-w-h)(z-w)}\right)\left(\frac{1}{z-w-h} + \frac{1}{z-w}\right) \:  dz\\ \\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_C f(z) \frac{1}{(z-w)^2}\frac{2}{z-w}  \: dz
\end{align}

Where in the last step the limit was swapped with the contour integral. Can one do it in this case? I'm pretty sure that not without proper justification.

How can one repair the proof?

Comment: Dominated convergence theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem

Comment: This is the Cauchy formula for derivates

Comment: @vvnitram: I know. The textbooks prove the more general n-th version (as opposed to just the second derivative in this case) and employ a more powerful technique which I wanted to avoid.